# butterworth filter for signal processing

Tags: matlab, signals

I have a school project to be able to move a wheelchair according to user instruction. I am currently starting my project by using matlab and have acquire several data for the training purpose. I am stuck at applying the butterworth filter to the signal,

this a sample of my training data 'go' [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Y0BvHzLaILaUpqeFpjWFV3eFE/view?usp=sharing/)

here is my code

```
[x,Fs] = audioread('go10.wav'); % to read the data

plot(x) ; % plot the data before aprplying the filter

n = 3; % the number of order

beginFreq = 800 / (Fs/2);
endFreq = 2000 / (Fs/2);
[b,a] = butter(n, [beginFreq, endFreq], 'bandpass');

y = filter(b, a, x);

figure;
plot(y) ; % plot the data after applying the filter

p = audioplayer(y,Fs);
play(p) ; % play the record after applying the filter
```

here the plotting result,
[image: this is the signal after the filter]

So my question is,

1) Did I do it right? about the begin and end frequency? and does my n correct?

2) And what can you tell me about this butterworth filter? I know that it trying to focus on the human voice, but what exactly it does?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your plot since it is in Time Domain, the best way to tell if you have it right is to plot in the Frequency Domain (by transforming your Time Domain signal into Frequency domain using fft). Your code looks okay otherwise. To understand the butterworth filter - or rather - the reason for different filter design, it is better to read from a paper/text book. I can tell you that the filter designed specifically for human speech interpretation is the Gamma Tone filter (also known as Cochleargram).

Comment: `beginFreq`, `endFreq` and `n` should be selected based on the application. It all depends on what you want to do with the filtered signal. But for voice in general I think that bandwidth is too small.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I see. I had read article about the butterworth filter. It sensitive to the human voice and will be able to remove the noise that was out of human frequency. And the human vocal frequency should be in a range of 100Hz - 3000Hz. (Correct me if I'm wrong) right?

Comment: @LuisMendo i think the frequency range should be from 100Hz - 3000Hz. But I am still confuse in the number of order `n` should be.

Comment: @amirulharry Strictly speaking (and according to majority of IEEE publications for vocal processing/recognition tasks) the human pitch frequency (fundamental frequency) ranges from 50Hz to 500Hz, the vocal frequency (not singing) is between 50Hz to 4000Hz. So your 100 Hz to 3000Hz should cover most of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

n, the order of the butterworth filter, determines how steep the transition from passband to stop band is. Higher n= sharper cutoff at the desired frequencies. Be aware though that large filter orders can make the filter unstable, as it is an IIR filter (infinite impulse repsonse, so it can ring forever).
You can check the amplitude/phase response of your filter with

```
freqz(b,a,NFFT,Fs)
```

Where NFFT is the desired frequency resolution , NFFT=2^15.
As this plot also will show, the butterworth filter has a nonlinear phase distortion, something to also consider when you use audio data.

If you process data off-line, you can use filtfilt instead of filt, to correct for the phase distortion (this will effectively double the filter order). This wont be a good option for real time processing though.